# Hide first modal then show show second modal on click function

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to close first modal then to show another modal with a form.
I have tried diffrent solution.It does not close the first modal but show the second modal behind the first modal.

Here is the code :

```
$('#WEITER').click(function() {
    $('#myModal5').data('modal', null);
    $('#myModal55').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to achieve this.

Try running the code snippet with full screen to see it working -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test1").click(function(){
      $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal('show');
       $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('hide');
    });
    
   $("#test2").click(function(){
      $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal('hide');
       $('.bs-example-modal-sm').modal('show');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<hr/>



<hr/>

<!-- 1 modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Show Modal1</button>


<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test2">Show Second/ Hide First</button>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2 modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Show modal2</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test1">Show First/ Hide Second</button>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why in my case do not work .Please go here http://meinumzugsberater.de/ then click >Kostenlos Angebote einholen then click weiter.

Comment: Go in the first link than you try what i have said in the first comment.

Comment: My problem is that my modal is not scrollable and is hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing specific code, it's difficult to give you a precise answer. However, from the Bootstrap docs, you can hide the modal like this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Then, show another modal once it's hidden:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    // Load up a new modal...
    $('#myModalNew').modal('show')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide other by using below code, hide other modal first then show second

```
$('#WEITER').click(function() {
$('#myModal5').modal('hide');
$('#myModal55').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap modal

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->



<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal 1-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">open new modal</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Modal 2-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You dont need to add a Js anymore. this is correct implementation